# <c:forEach> randomly doubles first or last item – is this a known bug?

Tags: jsf, jstl, richfaces

I've now spent about 3 hours debugging a strange behaviour with the following code snippet. I'm using a dynamic `<rich:dataTable>` with `<c:forEach>` to include a changing set of `<rich:column>` elements during runtime.

This works perfectly in 9/10 cases. **But sometimes the first or last column is doubled.** Have a look at the following stripped down example:

```
<f:subview id="sv-#{delegate.uuid}">

    <rich:dataTable value="#{TabellenDelegateHelper.findRowsTabelle(delegate)}" var="row" rows="#{TabellenDelegateHelper.map(delegate).rows}">
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Fixed Column" />
            </f:facet>
        </rich:column>

        <c:forEach var="theColumn" items="#{TabellenDelegateHelper.findColumns(delegate)}" varStatus="loop">
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{theColumn}" />
                </f:facet>
                <!-- stripped dynamic content -->
            </rich:column>
        </c:forEach>
    </rich:dataTable>

</f:subview>
```

That code is included in several views using the following snippet:

```
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/shared/tabelle.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="delegate" value="#{myTable}" />
</ui:include>
```

While debugging and even using simple `System.out.println(...)` statements the collection returned by `TabellenDelegateHelper.findColumns(delegate)` always contains the expected (not doubled) elements.

To further investigate I've added some more tags after the table:

```
<c:forEach var="theColumn" items="#{TabellenDelegateHelper.findColumns(delegate)}" varStatus="loop">
    <h:outputText value="#{theColumn}, " />
</c:forEach>
<br/>
<ui:repeat var="theColumn" value="#{TabellenDelegateHelper.findColumns(delegate)}" varStatus="loop">
    <h:outputText value="#{theColumn}; " />
</ui:repeat>
```

Those two loops generate different results:

[image: Example Image]

**Has anybody experienced this before?** I won't believe that JSTL Core is buggy... but so far I've no other clue.

Even more strange... if I reverse the order and append `<ui:repeat>` before `<c:forEach>` the collection is correct even if the table above shows the bug. Using `<c:forEach>` before `<ui:repeat>` before `<c:forEach>` the 1st is broken and the 2nd + 3rd output are correct.

To make it a little more detailed... the following `COLUMNS` are the ones returned by the method:

```
private static final String COL_FIRSTNAME  = "firstname";
private static final String COL_LASTNAME   = "lastname";
private static final String COL_TEAM       = "team";
private static final String COL_POSITION   = "position";
private static final String COL_ASSIGNMENT = "Aktion";

private static final List<String> COLUMNS = Arrays.asList(COL_FIRSTNAME, COL_LASTNAME, COL_TEAM, COL_POSITION, COL_ASSIGNMENT);
```

Comment: please add code of `TabellenDelegateHelper.findColumns(delegate)` Is it static method, returning static COLUMNS variable?

Comment: It's a simple `public List<String> findColumns(TabellenDelegate delegate) { return delegate.findColumns(); }` which returns the exact static list. I've also double checked if the delegate is the proper one.

Comment: Try to return new Collection every time in that helper method. (replace COLUMNS to Arrays.asList(...)) I don't know how implemented forEach inside, but maybe iterating over mutable non-synchronized static collection in multy-thread environment is not very good idea in any case.

Comment: Already tried it... `return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(COL_FIRSTNAME, COL_LASTNAME, COL_TEAM, COL_POSITION, COL_ASSIGNMENT));` didn't change anything for me... very strange.

Comment: The table is part of `table.xhtml` that is reused via `<ui:include>` with a `<ui:param>` for the `delegate`... but the `table.xhtml` itself starts with an `<f:subview>` to separate the namespace for all component IDs. So far I could only reproduce the bug with more than 1 `table.xhtml` on the same page... so maybe thats related. I've added that detail in the description.

Comment: Today I've realised that my `delegate` is wrapped twice... one as `$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy` and another one as `$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass` – the proxy is used by @Inject and the Subclass by XHTML or `<c:forEach>`... not sure why and if it's related to my problem here.

Comment: That particular question has not been answered but we completely skipped RichFaces meanwhile and built the whole table solely with JSF standard tags and loops. This way we could solve our bug. But I'm still not sure where the initial problem came from.

Comment: You should not be using RichFaces at this date and time, or indeed, judging by my experience, at any other date and time either. The product was thankfully discontinued in 2016 after more than one disaster.